# Codeigniter validation library extension is not working

Tags: validation, codeigniter

I have extended CI form validation library as following:

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    function __construct($config = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($config);
    }

    function check_first_char($str) 
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $first_char = substr($str, 0, 1);
        if ($first_char != 'P' || $first_char != 'S') 
        {
            $CI->form_validation->set_message('check_first_char', 'The %s field must begin with P or S!');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

and calling it like following:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('sponsor_id', 'Sponsor ID', 'trim|required|exact_length[7]|check_first_char');
```

But it is not working. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "not working" means?

Comment: I have done what you suggested but it still not working. and not working means if I pass a value other than something starting with P or S it shows no validation error and parse the data to DB.

Comment: Are any other validation rules working? Are you correctly loading the Form_validation library?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to initialize the library in your controller:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('sponsor_id', 'Sponsor ID', 'trim|required|exact_length[7]|callback_check_first_char');
```

If i'm not mistaken, you'll need the 'callback_'

Source: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Edit: And you'll also need to initialise the form_validation library.

Comment: I don't think that's the case here because the validation rule is being defined in the extended Form_validation class and *not* a controller like in the example you linked to. To that end, it acts like any of the other native validation rules and shouldn't need the `callback_` prefix.